# i have angular.min.js:129 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') error in my spring boot aplication

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to desingn login page by angular in my java Spring Boot Aplication. My problem is when I try login to panel page,username and password is ok and send to application by api controller and set user token correctly,but token don't set by cookeis in page, therefor panel page don't open and i have this error in inspect console :
[image]

[image]

[image]
my login page:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Online Shop App | login</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/ApiHandler.js"></script>
    <link href="libs/bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="libs/bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="styles/login.css" rel="stylesheet">


</head>
<body ng-app="onlineShopApp">
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col login-box-holder">
            <form>
                <h3>Login To Panel</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="user.userName">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" autocomplete="false"
                           ng-model="user.password">
                    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">Do not share your username and password</div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doLogin()">Login</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my login controller:

```js
    app.controller("loginCtrl", function ($scope, apiHandler, $cookies) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.doLogin = () => {
        apiHandler.callPost(
            'user/login',
            $scope.user,
            (response) => {
                var token=response.datalist[0].token;
                $cookies.put("userToken",token);
                if(token==null || token=="")
                {
                    alert("invalid token");
                    return;
                }
                $cookies.put("uerToken",token);
                alert("token is:");
                location.href="/panel";
            }, (error) => {
            });
    }
});
```

my panel page:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Online Shop App | panel</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="libs/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/panelController.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/ApiHandler.js"></script>
    <link href="libs/bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="libs/bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="onlineShopApp">
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="panelCtrl">
    <div class="row">
     <h3>Panel</h3>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my panel controller:
app.controller("panelCtrl", function ($scope, apiHandler, $cookies) {

```
$scope.checkAccess = () => {
var token=$cookies.get("userToken");
if(token==undefined || token==null || token==""){
location.href="/login";
}
}
$scope.checkAccess();
```

});

Comment: it's more likely due to `response.datalist[0]`, it means there is no `datalist` in `response`

Comment: @GérômeGrignon datalist in response contains information including username, token and other infotmation

Comment: @GérômeGrignon tank you for your comment, i checked again datalist on next line: i type wrong dataList in loginController. (i 
change response.datalist[0] to=> response.dataList[0] )

Comment: I encourage you to use Typescript to create an interface to type your data, it'll help you in such a situation by throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

i type wrong dataList in loginController file: (i change response.datalist[0] to=> response.dataList[0] )